# Why is subprocess.py throwing a WindowsError?

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, subprocess, windowserror

I'm trying to use the testing.postgresql package to test a few scripts and am running into this error upon instantiating testing.postgresql.Postgresql() or testing.postgresql.PostgresqlFactory():

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\testing\common\database.py", line 83, in __init__
  self.initialize()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\testing\postgresql.py", line 50, in initialize
  self.initdb = find_program('initdb', ['bin'])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\testing\postgresql.py", line 134, in find_program
  path = get_path_of(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\testing\common\database.py", line 288, in get_path_of
  stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 960, in _execute_child
  startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

From what I can find by following the trace and searching online, subprocess.py is failing to find initdb.exe. Exactly why is made murkier by subprocess.py handing off to an extension module, _subprocess.c.

I already tried adding the directory containing initdb to the system PATH, no dice.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, or any insight on what's going on here?

Comment: Depending on how you added the directory to the path, you might need to reboot in order for it to kick in.  [Nitpicker's corner: no, a reboot isn't strictly necessary, but it is reliable and easy to describe.]

Comment: @HarryJohnston tried that already, didn't work.

Comment: @eryksun I just checked, the directory is in os.environ['PATH'] with escaped backslashes, no quotes, no whitespace

Comment: @eryksun print shows it without doubled backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing the source, it doesn't appear that this is compatible with Windows. The package expects a UNIX-style environment.

[testing.postgresql/src/testing/postgresql.py](https://github.com/tk0miya/testing.postgresql/blob/master/src/testing/postgresql.py)

```
def find_program(name, subdirs):
     path = get_path_of(name)
     if path:
        return path

    for base_dir in SEARCH_PATHS:
        for subdir in subdirs:
            path = os.path.join(base_dir, subdir, name)
            if os.path.exists(path):
                return path

     raise RuntimeError("command not found: %s" % name)
```

[testing.common.database](https://github.com/tk0miya/testing.common.database/blob/master/src/testing/common/database.py)

```
def get_path_of(name):
     path = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/which', name],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
     if path:
         return path.rstrip().decode('utf-8')
     else:
         return None
```

*edited* to show correct source of problem per @eryksun's comment below.

Comment: This was my initial thought but if you look at the definition for _execute_child() in subprocess.py (line 846 at this outdated version [here](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py)) this appears to be written explicitly for Windows

Comment: The problem isn't with `subprocess`, that'll work fine on Windows, it's with the `testing.postgresql package`. It's looking for initdb at `C:\usr\...` or `C:\opt\...` per the SEARCH_PATHS.

Comment: It's failing before that when it calls `get_path_of('initdb')`. The function [`get_path_of`](https://github.com/tk0miya/testing.common.database/blob/1.1.0/src/testing/common/database.py#L285) tries to execute `/usr/bin/which`.

Comment: Ok, I see. `subprocess` is failing because it can't find `which`, not `initdb`. In  _which_ case you are correct @miyamoto that testing.postgresql will not work on Windows. Thanks for the help, both of you!